# Conversion of Enum to Enumerable

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

To convert Enum to Enumerable ,I use

```
public enum Flags
    {
        Trivial=1,
        Minor,
        Major,
        Critical
    }

IEnumerable<int> n = 
Enumerable.Range((int)Flags.Trivial, (int)Flags.Critical).OfType<int>();
```

Just I want to know whether it is a valid conversion or not (code is working).

Answer (score 4):

This way you can handle a not sequential enum:

```
IEnumerable<int> n = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Flags))
        .OfType<Flags>()
        .Select(e => (int)e);
```